# How could Bran get away?

Tags: game-of-thrones

At the end of episode 5 in season 6 of *Game of Thrones*:

> while Hodor holds the door to prevent the White Walkers from getting outside the heart tree's cave, Bran and Mira flee through the storm.

Given that

> Bran is marked by the Walker and that the army does not fear the storm (these frozen guys live in this storm 24/7)

how does it make sense that Bran has a chance to actually get away from his pursuers? Is it because we can expect

> Hodor to hold the door for a very long time even after he's dead? I would expect the army to catch up on him very easily in the next episode.

Edit: To add clarity,

> at the end of the episode I felt like Bran and Mira managed to escape since they disappear in the storm. It was a relief in some sense. However it seems that there is no reason to expect them to have actually escaped for the reasons mentioned above. As clear from the comments, there must be an upcoming trick for them to get away. I was not asking for what the trick would be though.

Comment: I was curious about that problem too. Maybe we will have an answer next Monday, or one of the following Mondays. It seems to me that any other answers are just speculations. Maybe there is the location nearby which have even more powerful protection against undead. Maybe eagles will suddenly appear and will rescue them.

Comment: I don't really think this is a question that can be directly answered without simply waiting to find out. However, if we were to speculate I imagine Bran will probably find some new power just in time, or warg into a white walker perhaps.

Comment: @BigTallJosh I hope that his superpower would be to hide from enemies, not to destroy them, because destroying would make him too powerful, and the plot with Night Watch and any preparations for fight useless

Comment: maybe coldhands with come to help

Comment: @Schullz I completely agree, any offensive powers I think are a bit ill-suited for the character but it is a common trope that the "hero" so to speak finds the power just when it's needed so I'm not ruling anything out.  If I had to put my money on something I'm leaning towards some sort of teleport or time freeze. Given that we have seen him interacting with the past I don't think it's too much of a stretch

Comment: I'm closing this question as primarily opinion-based per [our policy on questions about future works](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/should-questions-about-future-works-be-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based) - it will only be answerable after the next episode has aired. Feel free to flag it for reopening at that point; it will then be on-topic, but presumably trivial, so you may have to expect more downvotes.

Comment: I hope the irony of a question about the *Game of Thrones* episode "The Door" being put on hold isn't lost on anyone.

Comment: @DrRDizzle Too soon man, too soon. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you really want spoilers? Would you not be happier waiting less than a week to see how / if he gets away?

Of course it hasn't been revealed yet, but there is a theory based on officially released preview footage and casting announcements:

> [image: footage supposedly showing a rider rescuing Bran and Meera, and cast info showing the return of the actor who played Benjen Stark]

Comment: This is a link-only answer.

Comment: @anaranjada I've converted it into an embedded single image, retaining a link to the source.

Comment: @recognizer Much better. Thanks.

Comment: These pictures are far too dark; they don't show anything.

Comment: This may be it. This must be why its called 'Blood of my blood'. It remarks over Benjen and Bran's relationship. Good job, Mikey Mouse.